# Canon destiny of Fox father in the original SNES era games

Tags: video-games, canon, star-fox

> **Notice:** this question is about the original Star Fox saga started in the SNES era. The recent Wii-U reboot seem to have changed some of the original plot - including the elements I am asking about. Please do not reference that game when answering.

In the SNES game Star Fox we see Fox McCloud fighting alongside his team against Andross who is trying to conquer the Lylat system. In the game we discover that Fox father James McCloud was once the old leader of the Star Fox team, but he was "lost" during some not-so-well specified event during the war. In the recent remake, it is pretty much said that he probably sacrificed himself to save Peppy when one of the original team members betrayed him, but the older games - while retaining the betrayal part - are less clear on what was the destiny of the old hero.

While the game itself is pretty vague, some weird hints seems to be hidden in one of the game two "secret" levels. This level - named I think "The Awesome Black Hole" is pretty weird, having multiple exit that can bring the player to one of three different levels: in a way, this is a sort of a warp zone in a Mario game, allowing one to skip some levels.

The level itself is pretty strange too, begin a sort of cemetery for drifting spaceship parts, broken robots and the such. De-active enemies float in the air, as the player proceeds in a looping level that only ends when one of the three exit warp rings is crossed.

Anyway, what made me thinking is the dialogue showed when the player enters the level. The Colonel that usually gives briefing before each mission describes the black hole as "a space cemetery created by Andross" and tells Fox that this is "where his father **vanished**".

As many have already pointed out, most of the following games seem to hint that James was actually killed - the Star Wolf crew reference this, James ghost helps Fox in multiple occasion but no one is able to see him etc.

Then - why the first game seem to indicate that he is considered "lost in space" instead? Is there any reference to some original plot ideas that had James McCloud still alive, hiding somewhere? Or was that just a translation issue (or simply wanting to avoid the word "dead" in the SNES era - something very plausible if we consider that back then Nintendo was pretty strict to its family friendly game rule).

Comment: The Japanese version of the StarFox 64 manual explicitly states that he died; http://uk.ign.com/articles/1997/05/14/starfox-64-manual-translation-pt1. In the English version it's slightly more ambiguous.

Comment: James also makes an appearance in the Star Fox Command game for DS, in which it is explicitly stated that Fox is the only one who can see him. Falco even says "You seein' things? There's nobody there!". There are other things, such as Pigma's taunts during Lylat Wars, "Daddy screamed REAL good before he died!", and "Daddy's gonna be waiting for you in hell!"  in the Japanese version.

Comment: @Valorum thanks for the info. This somehow reinforces my idea that either the level was supposed to be an in-game joke and offer no real info about the plot, or the original plot was rectified far before the WiiU reboot.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo I think that one of those games was marked as not-canon, but yes, you have a point too. I was more interested about comments from the original developers about the particular level I mentioned, but the info you both provided are also interesting. I will try to recover some actual in-game shoots for the secret level.

Comment: It's a good question, but you may taking the idea of canon a bit seriously for a video game. When Star Fox first came out, Star Wars video games were notoriously horrible, and while Star Fox is not a ripoff of Star Wars, on some level I think they just wanted to provide a space game with surprise revelations about a father,  that was actually good.

Comment: @SegNerd - I don't believe that I am overthinking it. It's not like I want to know every detail or expect an ultra-complex plot... I just wonder if there is some indication if they intended to have James McCloud be dead from the start or they simply dropped the "James return" subplot halfway. The game seem to contradict itself there.

Comment: I wasn't accusing you of overthinking it. I just meant that video games tend to be somewhat non-canonical, and the story sometimes changes across different games in a series, without any explanation. With most games, the story is really just a "background" element to gameplay. Throw in some issues with multilingual translations, and I just meant that I don't expect video game stories to be as clear and consistent as, say, a movie or book.